# Can't access to transitive maven module's code

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, codehighlighter

This is about Intellij IDEA + Maven modules. We working in module A, which has a dependency - module B, and module B in dependencies - module C. When you incude B as a dependency and access classes from C (transitively), IDEA says that it does not understand what classes you import, it writes Cannot find symbol... and highlights such classes in red. However, mvn package is successfull and application starts. Workaround to enable code highlighitng - direct reference in the "Project structure -> modules" to the desired module, which is used transitively.

Comment: Dependencies should be configured correctly according to what you have defined in pom.xml. If it doesn't work properly, please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) attached. See also the comments at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-169064.

Comment: It is not recommended to access transitive classes directly.